# git checkout a pull request branch on your own fork

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-checkout, git-remote

We have this original repo called `origin` that all of us fork from and make changes.

I have a fork of this original repo called `fork1` my friend has a fork of this original repo called `fork2`.

Today, he made changes on `fork2` on branch `feature` and wanted to open a pull request to merge the branch `feature` to `origin`
To approve his pull request, I wanted to test out `feature` on my `fork1`. How should I do it?

Comment: Follow GitHub's instructions for [checking out a pull request locally](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), and then merge it into (or rebase it on top of) a local branch for testing.

Comment: the pull request is made to `origin` which I don't have access to, ideally I should be testing the branch on `fork1`, which is my fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the pull request is made to origin which I don't have access to

But you might have access to fork2, which means you could:

- add fork2 as a remote to your own local repository
- fetch from fork2
- try and checkout or merge fork2/feature, to test if it is working.

Comment: that means no matter what I'll have to have read access to fork2's repo?

Comment: @ChiaYi Yes, since you don't have access to origin where the PR is done.

Comment: If I were to get the access for origin, what could be done? I'm curious to know

Comment: @ChiaYi Yes, with access to the repo where the PR is done, then https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally applies.